# How to prevent a PDF file from direct URL Access in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, pdf

In my website i have storing user resume in Wordpress upload folder. I have created sub folder **resumeuploads** under the **wordpress wp-content/uploads/** folder. Now the resume are storing on the **resumeuploads** folder by using PHP code. Now i want to restrict the public access of PDF files on my website. If enter the http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/resumeuploads/my.pdf link on browser i can access the PDF files now i want to restrict that direct access. I have tried below code in htaccess but its not working for me. Could you please help me to solve the issue .

Code 1

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|pdf)$ - [F]
```

Code 2

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(pdf|zip)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ dl-file.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Or is there any way to redirect when accessing the pdf file url into home page???

Comment: @anubhava why that code is need ??

Comment: My doubt is why this code are not working ??

Comment: I have tested with default wordpress install still its not working so the php code is not issue

Comment: is there any way to redirect the url to home page ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deny access to all pdf files in the folder, try this in .htaccess:

```
# Deny access to files with extensions .pdf
<FilesMatch "\.(pdf)$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all

</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Not working i have tested on default wordpress install

Comment: So you can still access the pdf file? Is .htaccess placed in resumeuploads folder?

Comment: Yes its placed on that folder

Comment: Is your webserver apache2?

Comment: Yes using apache2

Comment: Did you enable it in the apache2 config file? You need to set `AllowOverride All` and then restart apache2

Comment: Did you try any other setting for .htaccess? for example how to stop people from accessing .htaccess file directly in the browser? Please also give some system info. What is the linux distro + version, apache version, did you install on a VPS or a home computer?